# How to implement a search and filter into HTML divs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm working on a website as part of a project. The idea is to be able to filter the div tags by their title. For example, if you wanted to search for 'Television' or 'Music', etc.

My idea was to use the ID for each div to search and filter. Any advice on how to do that or any method is greatly appreciated!

Search bar:

```
<input id="search-bar" class="options-button" type="text" placeholder="Search Categories...">
```

Div tags to be search:

```
<div class="discover-tile" id="television">
       <h2 class="discover-title">Television</h2>
       <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
       <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
<div class="discover-tile" id="movies">
       <h2 class="discover-title">Movies</h2>
       <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
       <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
<div class="discover-tile" id="music">
       <h2 class="discover-title">Music</h2>
       <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
       <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
```

CSS for the divs:

```
.discover-subscribe, .discover-unsubscribe {
    width: calc(100% + 14px);
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: white;
    background: #63c401;
    border: none;
    font-size: 14px;
    margin: 14px 0 -14px -14px;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.4) 0 0 6px;
    box-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.3) 0 0 4px;
    transition: background 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.discover-unsubscribe {
    background: #DE1B1B;
}
.discover-subscribe:hover {
    background: #52A301;
}
.discover-unsubscribe:hover {
    background: #B81616;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a tour of the [help centre](http://stackoverflow.com/help) to see [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and what types of question are [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for the site

Answer (score 0):

Try the following way with Array's `forEach()`:

```js
var divEl = document.querySelectorAll('div.discover-tile');
divEl.forEach(function(d){
  if(d.getAttribute('id') == 'television'){
    console.log(d);
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="discover-tile" id="television">
       <h2 class="discover-title">Television</h2>
       <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
       <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
<div class="discover-tile" id="movies">
       <h2 class="discover-title">Movies</h2>
       <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
       <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
<div class="discover-tile" id="music">
       <h2 class="discover-title">Music</h2>
       <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
       <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
```

Or you can use `filter()` like:

```js
var divEl = document.querySelectorAll('div.discover-tile');
var television = Array.prototype.filter.call(divEl, function(d){
  return d.getAttribute('id') == 'television';
});

console.log(television);
```

```html
<div class="discover-tile" id="television">
   <h2 class="discover-title">Television</h2>
   <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
   <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
<div class="discover-tile" id="movies">
   <h2 class="discover-title">Movies</h2>
   <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
   <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
<div class="discover-tile" id="music">
   <h2 class="discover-title">Music</h2>
   <p class="discover-info">Description</p>
   <button type="submit" class="discover-unsubscribe">Unsubscribe</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answers presented don't cover all the gotchas that you will run into. I would suggest you try using list.js to filter - it is very powerful and has a very small footprint.

http://listjs.com/

I've used it on several projects and it is rock solid and easy to setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in the following way:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myInput").on("keyup", function() {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    $("#myList div").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <h2>
example to filter div content</h2>
  <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search..">
  <br>
  <div class="list-group" id="myList">
  <div>Label 1</div>
  <div>Label 2</div>
  <div>asdf 1</div>
  <div>asdf 2</div>
  </div>  
</div>
```